# Swift initialization of superclass fails when initializing subclass of subclass

Tags: swift, initialization, subclass

Initialization of a super class fails when allocating subclass of a subclass.  My Classes

```
import Foundation
class GrandParent {
    var grandparent : Int = 1
    init () {
    }
}
class Parent : GrandParent {
    var parent : Int = 2
    override init () {
       super.init()
    }
}
class Child : Parent {
    var child : Int = 3
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I invoke with:

```
var aGrandParent=GrandParent()
var aParent=Parent()
var aChild=Child()

aGrandParent.grandparent is 1<br>
aParent.grandparent is 1<br>
aChild.grandparent is 6829487575  I expected it to be 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. All expression evaluate to 1, tested with Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.3 beta.

Comment: I tested [your code](http://pastebin.com/JSgkdvcT) online [here](http://www.runswiftlang.com/), and it worked as expected (I got three ones).

Comment: i am using Xcode Version 6.3 (6D520o) with swift 1.2

Comment: problem was with Xcode; if used println then the correct value shows.  if display object with Xcode then value displays incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with Xcode.  if the variable is printed (using println ) then the value is correct.  If it displayed in Xcode (either in the variables view or as expr aChild) then the value is displayed wrong.